# how to retrieve input value of html form if form is in django for loop

Tags: python, django, forms

I got a situation.I have a django template ip_form.html given bellow.

```
<form method = "GET">
  {% for val in value_list %}
    <input type='text' value = '{{ val }}'> {{ val }}</input>
  {% endfor %}
</form>
```

I want to tell you that, I have unknown no of val in value_list(may be zero). So may not use django form.py( and also I am getting value in certain time of a particular view function, i.e. don't know weather it will occur all time)

Let's say in views.py

```
def view1(request):
 value_list = [1,2,3,4,5] # it will change every time view1 will get request
 if request.method == "GET":
    # i want to retrieve here post
 return render ('ip_form.html','value_list':value_list)
```

How can i use form.py

So how can I retrieve it. You can refer me post method.(Its not a sensitive data so no problem with get method)

Thanks.

Comment: You should look into django formsets.

Comment: I read forms of django but it only show the way of forms.py

Comment: You need to explain bit more

Comment: I have edited, Please check the update

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a `name` attribute to your inputs, and then you can use this name to retrieve a list of values, using [Django QueryDict `getlist` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist):

HTML:

```
<form method="POST">
  {% for val in value_list %}
    <input type='text' value='{{ val }}' name='my_list'>{{ val }}</input>
  {% endfor %}
</form>
```

View:

```
def view1(request):
    value_list = [1,2,3,4,5] # it will change every time view1 will get request
    if request.method == "POST":
        values_from_user = request.POST.getlist('my_list')
    return render ('ip_form.html', 'value_list': value_list)
```

`values_from_user` will be a list of input values from your form (or an empty list if form had zero `input` elements).

Please note that I changed your form method to `POST`, because otherwise the `request.method` test in your view would be meaningless.

Comment: Thanks, So I need not to use form.py and what about to check form.is_valid

Comment: I showed you a way to do this without using the built-in [Django Forms Frakework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/), because that's what you asked about. You can achieve a similar effect using the framework, and one could argue you should. The `is_valid` method comes with the framework, so it is not available while using the approach shown above.