# Retrieving data from an array of check boxes in a Django template

Tags: django, django-templates

In a Django template, I'm displaying some usernames (or `unames`) along with check boxes like so:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'process_unames' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for name in unames %}
        <input type="checkbox" name="target{{ forloop.counter0 }}" value="{{ unames|index:forloop.counter0 }}" checked>{{ name }}<br>
    {% endfor %}
    <button name="duration" value="{{ value }}" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And then in the function `process_unames`, I'm trying to retrieve all **checked** unames via:

```
def process_unames(request, *args, **kwargs):
    uname_list = request.POST.getlist('unames')
```

This is consistently yielding an *empty list*, regardless of which uname I check or uncheck. How do I fix this? An illustrative example would be great.

---

In case it matters, I haven't declared any form in `forms.py` with this Django template. Moreover, note that `index` is a custom template tag which does the following (and I can vouch it's correctly working):

```
from django.template.defaulttags import register

@register.filter(name='index')
def index(List, i):
    return List[int(i)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking the wrong variable. You access the input by its name.

So for a single  value you would retrieve the data for a form like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="user_name" value={{uname}}>
```

via

```
request.POST.get('user_name')
```

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#the-work-that-needs-to-be-done

And if you have loop, you still give each relevant input the same name and use [`request.POST.getlist()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) to access the values as a list.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23470119/630877

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any fields called "unames" in the template. You have a bunch of unrelated checkboxes called "targetX" where X is a number. Replace that with just `name="unames"` and your code will work.

Note two things: firstly, you should be using Django's forms framework; and secondly, your filter is pointless because `{{ name }}` would already by the value in `unames`, since that is what you are iterating over (and, indeed, you are already using that as the label).

```
{% for name in unames %}
    <input type="checkbox" name="unames" value="{{ name }}" checked>{{ name }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```